# switch two <a> tag elements on the nav in the DOM wth event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now i am working on trying to swap the order of  tags on a menu so that they still maintain there event listeners and change order on the front end. For example,

```
 <a id = "A" href = ""></a>
 <a id = "B" href = ""></a>
 <a id = "C" href = ""></a>
 <a id = "D" href = ""></a>
```

Swap A, B, C, D to any position and at the same time switch them on the front end to represent the same order. 
Ive tried many different functions like append(), next(), however none work in a way that consistent.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ...and do you want the same order of items in your menu or the same order of `id`s?

Comment: Did I understand you correct? You want to move the elements for example per drag&drop or buttons (up&down). In case you are doing that you want to keep your .on("click") listeners?

Comment: lets see that javascript son

Comment: thanks! sorry for the poor wording hard to explain it. take for example a one scroll page with a sticky nav on top with a HOME ABOUT CONTACT <a> tags. I want to be able to switch them around through the DOM. So it would be ABOUT HOME CONTACT or CONTACT ABOUT HOME.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb lol i have tried a bunch of function just hard to explain

Answer (score 1):

This will move your clicked element to the first position. I don't know if that is what you are looking for in a small example, because I haven't understand your issue to 100%. If I have understood you correctly you are looking for a way to change the order of your elements. This is a simple example how you are able to move an element to the frist position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#uniqueWrapper').on('click', 'a', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
      $(this).prependTo("#uniqueWrapper");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="uniqueWrapper">
  <a id = "A" href = "#">A </a>
  <a id = "B" href = "#">B </a>
  <a id = "C" href = "#">C </a>
  <a id = "D" href = "#">D </a>
<div>
```

Comment: thanks! sorry for the poor wording hard to explain it. take for example a one scroll page with a sticky nav on top with a HOME ABOUT CONTACT <a> tags. I want to be able to switch them around through the DOM. So it would be ABOUT HOME CONTACT or CONTACT ABOUT HOME.

Comment: Yes then you should have a look or google for prepentTo and appendTo. That should do the trick as in my example.